# Multiple Upload Thumbnail

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com um campo para upload de documentos em PDF, ao anexar um documento aparece o ícone do PDF, porém estou utilizando upload múltiplo e aparece somente um ícone quando o ideal seria que aparecesse um ícone para cada arquivo anexado, sei que é possível mas não tenho muito conhecimento de Js, alguém poderia ajudar?

Código:
HTML

```
  <label id="timg" for="upload-photo">Upload <i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-
    hidden="true"></i></label> 
<input type="file" multiple id="upload-photo" required accept=".pdf, application/pdf">

<div id="thumbs"> 
<img src="" id="pdfimg" style="display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px;"/> </div>
```

JS

```
const icons = {

'application/pdf': 'http://iconbug.com/data/5b/507/52ff0e80b07d28b590bbc4b30befde52.png',

}

const input = document.querySelector('#upload-photo');
const image = document.querySelector('#pdfimg');         //Script PDF MultipleUpload
input.addEventListener('change', function() {
const tipo = this.files[0].type;
image.src = icons[tipo];

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens que declarar todos os ícones no objeto `icons`, no exemplo abaixo adicionei um ícone para representar a imagem de um arquivo do tipo `image/png`. Sempre que há mudança no `input` é criada uma imagem para arquivo que foi enviado, baseada no seu tipo.

```js
const icons = {
  'application/pdf':'http://iconbug.com/data/5b/507/52ff0e80b07d28b590bbc4b30befde52.png',
  'image/png': 'http://findicons.com/files/icons/1637/file_icons_vs_2/256/png.png'
}

const input = document.querySelector('#upload-photo');
const thumbs = document.querySelector('#thumbs');
input.addEventListener('change', function() {
  thumbs.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = icons[this.files[i].type];
    img.className = "thumbImg";
    thumbs.appendChild(img);
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = this.files[i].name;
    thumbs.appendChild(span);
  }
});
```

```css
.thumbImg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<label id="timg" for="upload-photo">Upload <i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-
    hidden="true"></i></label>
<input type="file" multiple id="upload-photo" required accept=".pdf, application/pdf">

<div id="thumbs">
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, deu tudo certo, só mais uma pergunta é possível mostrar o nome do arquivo embaixo da imagem, quando anexado?

Comment: @HenriqueBretone É sim, editei a resposta, adicionei um `span` com o nome (`this.files[i].name`) logo após a imagem =)

Comment: Valeu mesmo cara salvou minha vida sério.